# PHP not executing in installed phpMyAdmin directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I installed phpmyadmin on centos via yum and can access it via `//ip/phpMyAdmin`.

However, it shows the source code instead of the interpreted PHP code result.

I tested this again by adding another file, `test.php` with just the contents `""` and sure enough in this case too the source code was displayed.

I have other sites on this server installed for which php works just fine. These are in the `/home` directory however, and phpmyadmin is installed in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin`

What could be the cause of this? It's certainly nothing to do with short tags since my test.php doesn't use that..

Note that I use webmin, might this have something to do with it? Webmin/virtualmin use php in fcgi mode by default, which I would like to keep that way..

I have added:

```
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All 
Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,Sy$
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/ubn/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/ubn/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
```

But now get an internal server error with seemingly no entry in the error_log

Comment: The answers here may be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess Also, can you confirm you're using mod_php?

Comment: Please post all apache configurations relevant for CGI and PHP in particular.

Comment: @sebix it's the default virtualmin config, I have now copied what virtualmin creates for a virtual host and added that to the <Directory> config, but get an internal server error as a result, with no entry in error_log..

Comment: Could you check the config extract you've included? I think the AllowOverride line has been split in two and truncated ("Sy$" is probably "SymLinksIfOwnerMatch")

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualmin, by default sets up a system for name-based virtual hosting, with applications running under suxec, and usually under mod_fcgid, as you've noted. This is incompatible (in a couple of ways) with Apache serving a single non-name-based site (though you could make the site in /var/www into the default site, and enable mod_php for it, I don't recommend it for a variety of reasons, including security).

Virtualmin (both GPL and Professional versions) include a Script Installer for phpmyadmin. Use that to install phpmyadmin into a virtual host managed by Virtualmin, instead of trying to use the OS package, and it should Just Work. You can also have Virtualmin notify you of updates to the scripts you've installed with Install Scripts, and it is kept up to date at least as aggressively as the CentOS RPM, so you aren't trading ease of upgrading away when installing this way.

If you really want to use the RPM version of phpmyadmin, let me know, and I'll see if I can find some docs for it (we used to not include phpmyadmin in Virtualmin GPL, so we provided a few documents on how to make it work, but since adding some of the Install Scripts to GPL a few years back, that's less of a thing that gets talked about).